# Android - Are main.xml and activity_main.xml the same concept?

Tags: java, android

I'm taking an Android class based on this book: http://www.deitel.com/Books/Android/AndroidforProgrammers/tabid/3606/Default.aspx

Some example code, and the book, mention and used main.xml, yet some examples and the professors slides use activity_main.xml.  I think they are more or less the same concept, but I'm not clear on it, even after googling (I did find other people asking the same thing though).

Does it matter what the name of the "main" xml page is?  Or is it for human readability?

Is activity_main.xml the new convention that should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name your layout XML files whatever you please.

I prefer to prefix my layout files with `activty_` for Activity layouts, `fragment_` for fragment layouts, etc. A file named "main.xml" isn't very clear to me, especially because a "main" Activity might have a layout for both its Fragment and its Activity.

Use whatever naming scheme you think fits best. Android doesn't care.

Comment: This is the first I've heard of fragment layouts. What and when are those used?

Comment: Check out the [Developer's Guide page on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). They allow you to make much more modular layouts.

Comment: Cool thanks! I actually understood what it was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It is for human readability.
You may have more Activity on your project and it is necessary to name them properly in order to make your project clear and readable.
Read also [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) if you want more info!

Comment: Thanks, I've read that a few times.  i get the jist of what it's saying, but how does that have to do with layout xml files?

Comment: @allanonmage Tanis's answer was more useful, you have to accept it ;) .

Answer (score 0):

**Class name:** ActAboutUs. Prefixing class is kind of overkill but it clearly distinguishes activity classes from the others. Initially I used separate directory for all the activities (similar to your approach) but after some time I realized that for bigger apps may be it is better to group in directories by feature than by superclass (i.e. Activity). It is easier for me to work in single directory for example /src/settings/ when I work on Settings. That way all java files that I need are in a single dir so i don't have to wander around:

Some people preffer suffixes but I found them less useful. Prefixes help to group things alphabetically like in the example above: Act* prefix is sorted first so all activities are conveniently at the top.

I am even considering of using Act_ as a prefix which is more readable although it is in conflict with java naming conventions...

**Layout filename:** act_about_us.xml. In res/layout/ we don't have the "luxury" of subdirs which is quite unfortunate so the only way to group things is using appropriate prefix like act_, dlg_, etc...

**String IDs:**

(now I am realizing that activity_*element*_item (two underscores) is more clear and readable than activity_element_item)

All in all I still can't get rid of the feeling that there is something wrong with my approach because I can't believe that google devs created such an inconvenient framework when it comes to working with files, IDs, names, etc...